# Webpack dynamic import based on entry name

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to have Webpack to bundle specific files depending on the entry file.

I have multiple entry files in my project. They all use common helpers functions (separate modules), but some entry files use a slightly modified version.

Here's what I've done so far:

**`entry1.js`**

```
import helper from './helper';

helper();
```

---

**`entry2.js`**

```
import helper from './helper';

helper();
```

---

**`helper.js`**

```
import example from './example';

export default function helper() {
  console.log('common console log for Entry 1 and 2 pages');

  example();
}
```

---

**`example.js`**

```
const context = window.__CONTEXT__;

export default require(`./example_${context}`).default;
```

---

**`example_entry1.js`**

```
export default function() {
  console.log('specific console log for Entry 1 page only');
};
```

---

**`example_entry2.js`**

```
export default function() {
  console.log('specific console log for Entry 2 page only');
};
```

---

**`entry1.html`**

```
<script>
  window.__CONTEXT__ = 'entry1';
</script>
<script src="entry1.js" />
```

Browser's console output:

> common console log for Entry 1 and 2 pages
>
> specific console log for Entry 1 page only

---

**`entry2.html`**

```
<script>
  window.__CONTEXT__ = 'entry2';
</script>
<script src="entry2.js" />
```

Browser's console output:

> common console log for Entry 1 and 2 pages
>
> specific console log for Entry 2 page only

---

Is there a way to have something like this in `example.js`?

```
export default require(`./example_${__CURRENT_ENTRY_FILENAME__}`).default;
```

So, Webpack can bundle `entry1.js` and `entry2.js` with their specific helper modules!

And, that way, I'm hoping to get rid of *the terrible* `window.__CONTEXT__` in my `HTML` and `JS` files.

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your repo?

Comment: I have this type of work before in CRA. if you share repo then I will make webpack dependent solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Modules Dynamic imports](https://v8.dev/features/dynamic-import#dynamic) but you'll have to use promises:

#### `example.js`

```js
exports default (moduleName) => import(`./example_${moduleName}`);
```

#### `helper.js`

```js
import example from './example';

export default function helper() {
  example(__CURRENT_ENTRY_FILENAME__).then((module) => {
    console.log('common console log for Entry 1 and 2 pages');

    module.default();
  });
}
```